# Irreducible nonnegative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, nonnegative-matrices

I would like to aply this theorem in a pratic an exercise, the theorem i:
A nonnegative square matrix $A=\left(a_{ij}\right)$ is irreducible if and only 
if for each $(i, j)$ there exists an integer $к$ such that $a_{ij}^k>0$.

How do i find this integer k?
For example, give the matrix $A=\left[\begin{matrix} 
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]$

But i understand if i have to prove with the property $\left(I+A\right)^{n-1}$, because i know $n-1=3-1=2$

Answer (score 1):

$k$ depends on $i$ and $j$. If you view $A$ as an adjacency matrix for a directed graph $G$, so that $a_{ij}>0$ if and only if there is a directed arc in $G$ joining node $i$ to node $j$, then $(A^k)_{ij}>0$ if and only if there is a *path* of length $k$ joining node $i$ to node $j$.

In your example, the graph contains the following paths:
\begin{aligned}
&1\to2\to1,\\
&1\to2,\\
&1\to3,\\
&2\to1,\\
&2\to1\to2,\\
&2\to1\to3,\\
&3\to1,\\
&3\to1\to2,\\
&3\to1\to3.
\end{aligned}
Therefore, for $(i,j)=(1,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,2)$ and $(3,3)$, you may take $k=2$. For other $(i,j)$s, you may take $k=1$.